# Display a new link each time the pop-up is used

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am aiming to build a google chrome extension that displays a different link to a different website every time it is used.

That is, I have a list of websites and I want to iterate through the list such that each time I click the extension the next link is shown.

Currently my popup.html file looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My First Chrome Extension</title>
<style>
    #popup{
        width:300px;
        height:200px;
        text-align:center;
        line-height:200px;
    }
</style>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<div id="popup">
        <a href="some_link.com" target="_blank">next link</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

(the popup.js file is empty). When I click my extension icon, it will display a link to "some_url.com" which opens in a new tab (great). What I am looking for is to be able to then display "another link" when I click the extension icon again ("another link" being the next from some predefined list).

I would be very grateful for help/resources to be able to add this behaviour to the extension. I am new to chrome extensions (and javascript) and don't know where to go next.

Comment: Maybe keep a counter in the [store](https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/storage) and increment it each time a page is loaded? This way you know which index of the list you need to access and display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a anchor tag with some id on popup.html page

```
<a id="show-links" target="_blank"></a>
```

Then in your popup.js file, add a hfref attribute to this element using javascript

```
var a = document.getElementById('show-links');
//create an array with all links
links_array = ["some_link.com", "some_link1.com", "some_link2.com"];
//assign links to a from array at random
a.href = links_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * links_array.length)];
```